# AutoCompleteEditText selector, how it will be?

Tags: android, autocomplete, android-widget, css-selectors

I am using an `AutoCompleteEditText` and I want to make it appearance as [image]

But I don't know how it will be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general way to do this is by using 9-patch more info here http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/draw9patch.html. But in this case you can use simpler solution.

in your main layout

```
<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/searchfieldlayout" android:layout_height="46dp"
    android:background="#0000ff">
    <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="32dp" android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="7dp" android:layout_marginRight="7dp"
        android:background="@drawable/search_gradient">
        <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/search_icon"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" android:background="@drawable/search_icon">
        </ImageView>
        <EditText android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/searchfield"
            android:paddingTop="5dp" android:textSize="13dp" android:textColor="#ffffffff"
            android:selectAllOnFocus="true" android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp" android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/search_icon"
            android:background="@drawable/transparent_background"
            android:layout_marginLeft="7dp" android:inputType="text" android:imeOptions="actionGo">
         </EditText>
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

search_gradien.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient android:startColor="#2b0139" android:endColor="#3e1550"          android:angle="270" />
    <corners android:radius="6dp" />
</shape>
```

transparent_background.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient android:startColor="#00000000" android:endColor="#00000000"
        android:angle="270" />
</shape>
```

fix your colors or dimensions if needed.

Comment: its giving error, 03-15 15:12:09 - TestApplicationHeaderContact] /home/pankaj/android-sdk-linux_86/platform-tools/aapt: /lib/libz.so.1: no version information available (required by /home/pankaj/android-sdk-linux_86/platform-tools/aapt)
[2011-03-15 15:12:09 - TestApplicationHeaderContact] /home/pankaj/workspace/TestApplicationHeaderContact/res/layout/auto_text.xml:2: error: Error parsing XML: unbound prefix

Comment: Ok if you are using as root of your xml file you have to add xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

Comment: +1 Yes I was missing it. Now this is working perfectly. Thank you very much.